# it is required to measure the height of a tower. CB,which is inaccessible.

Tags: trigonometry

I found this question in an online math community. One of the posters uploaded a question which I'm interested to answer. He phrased the question like this:

> it is required to measure the height of a tower. CB,which is inaccessible. from point A, in the same horizontal plane with the base C, a right triangle CAD is turned, and a horizontal line AD, 150 feet in length, is measured. At A the angle of elevation of the top of the tower is 32 degrees, at D the angle of elevation is 28 degrees. find the height of the tower

How I understood it:

> It is required to measure the height of a tower, $CB$, which is inaccessible. From point $A$, in the same horizontal plane with the base $C$, a right triangle $CAD$ is formed, and a horizontal line $AD$, $150$ feet in length, is measured. At $A$, the angle of elevation of the top of the tower is $32^o$, at $D$ the angle of elevation is $28^o$. Find the height of the tower.

I don't understand the phrase "a right triangle $CAD$ is formed". With that in mind, I drawn the figure that describes the problem. Here's what I drawn:

[image]

Is my illustration correct? What do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not correct, actually it is something like that:

[image]

Where the right angles are CAD and BAD