# It is required to measure the height of a tower, CB, which is inaccessible

Tags: trigonometry

I found this question in an online math community. One of the posters uploaded a question which I'm interested to answer. The question looks like this:

> It is required to measure the height of a tower, $CB$, which is inaccessible. From point $A$, in the same horizontal plane with the base $C$, a right triangle $CAD$ is formed, and a horizontal line $AD$, $150$ feet in length, is measured. At $A$, the angle of elevation of the top of the tower is $32^o$, at D the angle of elevation is $28^o$. Find the height of the tower.

**My work**

After some inquiries, the figure described above would look like this:

[image]

I believe there will be a constant of proportionality involved in solving the height of the blue tower because I could build the figure in my mind using only the given figures in the problem, then if I changed the figure mentally by stretching it, another set of parameters will result in the new "given"....

But I don't know where to put this constant of proportionality, ending up scratching my head....

How to solve the above problem?

Comment: You could have just edited your [original question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2570040/it-is-required-to-measure-the-height-of-a-tower-cb-which-is-inaccessible), rather than posting a duplicate.

Comment: @dxiv im deleting it though.....if I just edited it,.....they will not see it again.....

Comment: Edits tend to pop the question back at the top of "active" or "recent" for a while. Edits pointing out what was left out from, or unsatisfactory about, previous answers can elicit new and better answers.

Comment: @dxiv oh I see......I thought edited questions will die in past....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [it is required to measure the height of a tower. CB,which is inaccessible.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2570040/it-is-required-to-measure-the-height-of-a-tower-cb-which-is-inaccessible)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From $\triangle ABC$, we get: $$ BC = AC \tan 32 \tag{1}$$ and from $\triangle BCD$, we get: $$BC = CD \tan 28 \tag{2}$$

Now, in $\triangle CAD$, we have: $$AD^2+AC^2=CD^2$$ $$\implies 150^2 = BC^2 [\frac{\tan^2 32 - \tan^2 28}{\tan^2 32 \tan^2 28}]$$ $$\implies BC = \, \, ?$$

Comment: @PalautotKa Have you understood the answer?

Comment: I don't know the correct answer.....but your solution looks nice....

Comment: Yes...I understand your way.....

Comment: Thanks for helping me out, man!